# Jump to current line being executed in cgdb

Tags: debugging, terminal, gdb, cgdb

Is it possible to jump to current line being executed in the Source Window of `cgdb`?

It would be great to have a command or a shortcut to do this, especially after browsing files in the File Dialog mode for a long time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that you can jump to current line easily: just use gdb `frame` command without arguments, or simply `f`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we have a shortcut for it. I usually do a quick `up` and `down` (or vice versa) in gdb.

Comment: Nice option, but what if you have just one stack frame? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'.`. Please please See https://github.com/cgdb/cgdb/issues/53

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).